# How to creat a squeezed-state light in integrated-photonic devices

Tags: optics, photons, non-linear-optics, photonics, squeezed-states

I am interested in studying (squeezed-state light in integrated-photonic devices by means of four-wave mixing).  I would like to be completely familiar with the working method and all the devices that are active in this process.
Is there a website or an article to fully understand how this system works that will provide complete information about how it works

Comment: The RP Photonics Encyclopedia is always a good place to start. https://www.rp-photonics.com/four_wave_mixing.html

Comment: This open access tutorial article goes into a lot of detail about the mathematics behind it https://opg.optica.org/aop/fulltext.cfm?uri=aop-14-3-291